# knp menu bundle symfony

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-2.5, knpmenubundle

I have been using a fos user Bundle where each of user is assigned to a group and each group is provided with a specific role as per fos user bundle everything works fine.

Now to make a menu system I am trying to use Knp menu bundle.Now to make menu structure I want to pass roles of each group to menu system(dynamically).So that changing role of specific group can allow the menu system to change dynamically.

I have already configured menu bundle as per documentation

[knp menu bundle documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#create-your-first-menu)

here I have added a class named menu builder inside namespace Admin\Bundle\HomeBundle\Menu; Now I need to call group roles of current logged in user and add them to menu dynamically also i need to make some of these roles to sub menu within same main menu.
Please improve me if I am on wrong way (if any) and process how I can dynamically include roles of group to menu using Knp menu bundle as a sevice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I find out another solution in Symfony 3. You can get `security.authorization_checker` from the container and use it in menu

```
namespace AppBundle\Menu;


use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

class Builder implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
   use ContainerAwareTrait;
   public function topHeaderMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
   {
      $checker = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
      $menu = $factory->createItem('root');
      $menu->setChildrenAttribute('class','links-top list-inline');
      if ($checker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $menu->addChild('admin panel', array('route' => 'admin'));
      }
      if ($checker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        $menu->addChild('account', array('route' => 'login'));
        $menu->addChild('logout', array('route' => 'logout'));
      } else {
        $menu->addChild('registration', array('route' => 'registration'));
        $menu->addChild('login', array('route' => 'login'));
      }

      return $menu;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony3 the best and easiest solution for me was in MenuBuilder.php :

```
use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class MenuBuilder implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
use ContainerAwareTrait;

public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
    $this->checker = $authorizationChecker;
}

public function mainMenu(array $options)
{
    $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
    $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));
    $menu->addChild('Blog', array('route' => 'blog_homepage'));
    $menu['Blog']->addChild('About', array('route' => 'blog_about'));
    $menu['Blog']->addChild('Contact Us', array('route' => 'blog_contact'));

    if($this->checker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {

        $menu->addChild('Admin', array('route' => 'sonata_admin_dashboard'));
    }
    $menu->addChild('User', array('route' => 'fos_user_profile_show'));
    $menu['User']->addChild('Register', array('route' => 'fos_user_registration_register'));
    $menu['User']->addChild('Change password', array('route' => 'fos_user_change_password'));
    $menu['User']->addChild('Log Out', array('route' => 'fos_user_security_logout'));
    // ... add more children

    return $menu;
}
}
```

Donf forget to add "@security.authorization_checker" to arguments in your service